# Laravel 4 route not working as expected

Tags: laravel-4

Thank you for taking the time to read this question. I have searched everywhere and cannot find the answer.

I am learning Laravel and are making a simple blog. I created a resource controller like so:

```
Route::resource('blog-posts', 'AdminBlogPostsController');
```

I was able to get all actions working fine (index, show, create, edit, update, delete) without any issues.

Since each blog post belongs to a category, I wanted the user to filter the blog-posts/index view by category, so I added this named route, BEFORE the resource declaration:

```
Route::get('blog-posts/{category_id?}', 'AdminBlogPostsController@index');
Route::resource('blog-posts', 'AdminBlogPostsController');
```

At this point, the user is able to filter by category just fine. However, if I navigate to

```
blog-posts/create
```

The browser simply displays blog-posts/index route, and I am unable to create a new record. If I comment out the first route like so:

```
//Route::get('blog-posts/{category_id?}', 'AdminBlogPostsController@index');
Route::resource('blog-posts', 'AdminBlogPostsController');
```

I am able to create blog posts again, but I am unable to filter the view.

Any ideas how to begin debugging this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a where condition at the end of the category route like so

```
Route::get('blog-posts/{category_id?}', 'AdminBlogPostsController@index')->where('category_id', '[0-9]+');
```

Basically this tells laravel to route to the index method if the second segment of the url is a digit.

Take a look at the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) page for some more examples of this.

Comment: That did it, and I learned something new. Thank you very much!